# not able to call admin block

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to call a template file using custom module.
i have created a admin module and calling admin controller function on button click.

```
public function updateccAction() {  

            $this->loadLayout();
           $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

now in 
in my app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/test.xml in trying to call that block using this code

```
 <test_mymodule_admin_autoship_updatecc>
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>autoship/popup.css</file></action>
                     </reference>
                     <reference name="content">
                         <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_customer_cards"  template="mymodule/customer/updatecc.phtml">
                    </block>
                    </reference>
        </test_mymodule_admin_autoship_updatecc>
```

this is my card.php block code.
Test/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Cards.php

```
class Test_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Cards extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    {

    }
```

in my module's updatecc.phtml i just used die();

when i run the code it doesn't call that updatecc.phtml file. It just shows empty page with header and footer.

but when i use in test.xml

```
<block type="adminhtml/template"  template="mymodule/customer/updatecc.phtml"/>
```

i am able to call updatecc.phtml file.
i need to call the custom admin block that is

```
 <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_customer_cards"  template="mymodule/customer/updatecc.phtml"/>
```

so that i can use the function in my template file please help.